# USB Ports No Longer Working

Tags: usb

A few days back I had tried to plug a cooling fan into one of my USB ports. Much to my dismay, it did not work. I unplugged my mouse and placed the cooling fan's plug into there, and it worked just fine, but on the other port it didn't change a thing. So out of confusion and curiosity, I replaced the now empty port with my mouse's receiver. It didn't work. Much to my dismay after replacing it back into it's usual port and using my Xbox 360 to power the cooling fan, now neither of the ports work. I'll paste the outpust of dmesg below with both ports empty, then with my mouse plugged into one port and a USB keyboard into the other. If my dmesg output is wrong, please notify me.

Dmesg output with empty ports:

```
[    1.520468] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.520476] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[    1.520772] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.520787] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.520796] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: applying AMD SB700/SB800/Hudson-2/3 EHCI dummy qh workaround
[    1.520811] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: debug port 1
[    1.520876] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: irq 17, io mem 0xd2306400
[    1.532066] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.532154] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.532158] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.532161] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.532164] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.16.0-45-generic ehci_hcd
[    1.532167] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:12.2
[    1.532396] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.532409] hub 1-0:1.0: 6 ports detected
[    1.532849] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
[    1.532877] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.532885] ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver
[    1.533105] ohci-pci 0000:00:12.0: OHCI PCI host controller
[    1.533115] ohci-pci 0000:00:12.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.533156] ohci-pci 0000:00:12.0: irq 16, io mem 0xd2305000
[    1.592118] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    1.592122] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
```

Dmesg output with mouse plugged in:

```
[    1.520468] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.520476] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[    1.520772] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.520787] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.520796] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: applying AMD SB700/SB800/Hudson-2/3 EHCI dummy qh workaround
[    1.520811] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: debug port 1
[    1.520876] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: irq 17, io mem 0xd2306400
[    1.532066] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.532154] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.532158] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.532161] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.532164] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.16.0-45-generic ehci_hcd
[    1.532167] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:12.2
[    1.532396] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.532409] hub 1-0:1.0: 6 ports detected
[    1.532849] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
[    1.532877] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.532885] ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver
[    1.533105] ohci-pci 0000:00:12.0: OHCI PCI host controller
[    1.533115] ohci-pci 0000:00:12.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.533156] ohci-pci 0000:00:12.0: irq 16, io mem 0xd2305000
[    1.592118] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    1.592122] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
```

Dmesg output with USB Keyboard and mouse plugged in:

```
[    1.520468] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.520476] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[    1.520772] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.520787] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.520796] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: applying AMD SB700/SB800/Hudson-2/3 EHCI dummy qh workaround
[    1.520811] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: debug port 1
[    1.520876] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: irq 17, io mem 0xd2306400
[    1.532066] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.532154] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.532158] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.532161] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.532164] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.16.0-45-generic ehci_hcd
[    1.532167] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:12.2
[    1.532396] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.532409] hub 1-0:1.0: 6 ports detected
[    1.532849] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
[    1.532877] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.532885] ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver
[    1.533105] ohci-pci 0000:00:12.0: OHCI PCI host controller
[    1.533115] ohci-pci 0000:00:12.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.533156] ohci-pci 0000:00:12.0: irq 16, io mem 0xd2305000
[    1.592118] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    1.592122] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
```

Now.. can anyone help me out here? What's wrong with the ports? Is it the ports are messed up physically? Or is this a hardware issue? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you burned a trace or blew a polyfuse on the motherboard.  The ports themselves are quite durable, but you can't trust those ports with high current devices like fans.

This is a hardware issue.  The cooling fan was never seen by software, and the cooling fan never saw the software.  All it did was pull 5VDC from the USB port.

Comment: What should I do to fix it? Is it fixable? I'm using a laptop cause the desktop I have, I don't know where the power cable to it went, and it's rather slow.

Comment: I don't think you can fix those.  You can however buy a USB3.1
 PCI express card: http://www.amazon.com/Two-Ports-Express-Profile-Bracket/dp/B00XAT4IH4/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1438909583&sr=8-1&keywords=usb+3.1+pci+express+card